# How do I create a meat like bite resistance/snap and texture in Vegan sausages?

Tags: vegan, sausages

I have been trying to create a vegan and gluten free sausage. The flavors thus far are tasty and enjoyable.  I just want a better snap/bite/tear when I bite into the dog.

I use soy isolate (I have tried pea isolate as well) to make an emulsion for fat delivery (canola oil). Am trying for a 'country' texture of chunks of visible veggies (cauliflower or eggplant or mushrooms or tomatoes etc.).  I use a TVP or a TPP as a filler to increase the sponginess a bit.

I have been trying gels of carrageenan and konjac powder, I have used guar gum and xanthan gums.  The gels work a bit but soften at temps above 150F.  The gums are not able to bind the core ingredients before the gumminess takes over.

I have experimented with methylcellulose but that too loses its texture at high temperatures and overwhelms the taste at high doses.

I want to replicate the 'tear' effect that the Beyond Sausage has when it is cooked to 200F or so.  According to their ingredient label they use coconut oils, pea proteins and methylcellulose.  But I can not seem to replicate their product.

I haven't been using coconut oil because it is a saturated fat and I wanted to avoid that if possible.  I am not sure the practical structural differences between sat fat and unsat fats with respect to this project.

Free beer/wine for whomever solves this riddle.

Comment: Based on personal experience, this isn't possible in a home kitchen without using gluten.

Comment: Beyond Sausage is gluten-free.

Comment: Tapioca flour? -Cheap at the Asian stores. I haven't tried it for this purpose, but it has some interesting gel forming properties.

Answer (score 3):

Zambian Chikanda has a meat (more of processed meat/saussage) like texture, it’s made using ground peanuts and orchid tubers. The polysaccharide (glucomannan) in the orchid tubers once cooked above a certain pH level, will form a heat stable gel upon cooling. I think this texture is what you’re looking for.

Even though you say you have tried Konjac powder (which also has GM in it) I think you should look into how it behaves in a high pH environment and with presence of fats.

Answer (score 1):

I'm puzzled that you say methylcellulose loses its texture at high temperatures. It forms a gel at high temperatures, like an egg white; the major difference is that it is vegan, and turns back to a liquid on cooling. You need about 1% to give a really good hot bite.

You can buy it online; make sure to look for E461 or methylcellulose.  Also, are you certain you had methylcellulose, rather than hydroxypropyl methylcellulose or sodium carboxymethyl cellulose?  Neither of these will work as desired, and I've seen them labelled incorrectly.

Comment: Linda, welcome! We are a bit sensitive when it comes to linking to own websites - not in the way that we consider it forbidden, but we must insist that these links should be clearly marked. You are of course welcome to register your user account and add the link to your profile. For all other potentially promotional content, see [this page](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) in our [help].